# Installing requirements via "python -m pip install" randomly throws WinError5 exception

Tags: python, windows, pip, pycharm

```
OS:     Windows 10, 64-bit
Python: 3.9.1
Pip:    21.0.1
Editor: JetBrains Pycharm 2020.3.3
```

I have cloned a private GitHub repository via Pycharm and created the project's `venv` as usual after selecting my project interpreter. Ran `python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip setuptools wheel` after. Versions of all modules are up-to-date.

Pycharm automatically activates the created `venv`, so there is no need to manually activate it.

When running `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt`, this error (seemingly) randomly occurs:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: {file_path within venv}
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

I have checked for this error, and all sources seem to imply a permission mismatch, but I cannot figure out why there would be any.

So, I opened `cmd` as admin, navigated to my project folder and activated the `venv` through `.\venv\Scripts\activate`. There was no issue here.

Naturally, I ran `python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall -r requirements.txt` and the same error still occurred - even with admin permissions. (pip seems to fail randomly - sometimes e.g. `numpy` is able to be installed, sometimes not)

What could I try next in order to make it work? Have I made any mistakes so far? How could I proceed?

### EDIT:

Using the `--user` flag does not work. `ERROR: Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.`

### EDIT 2:

Deleting the `venv` directory, and reinstalling it with the following commands seems to have fixed the issue when installing the project requirements for the first time:

```
python -m venv .\venv
.\venv\Scripts\activate
python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip setuptools wheel
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

The project is able to be run now, but out of curiosity, I tried running this command again:
`python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall -r requirements.txt`

The error still occurs, so it doesn't seem like the issue is fixed by recreating the `venv`, but at least the project can be run now. Not closing the question myself, as the "actual problem" does not seem to be fixed.

Comment: Have you tried adding `--user` to the end of the pip command?

Comment: This is not possible: `ERROR: Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.`

Comment: A tough one then. Could you try perhaps cloning the repo without pycharm and try the same process again (all without pycharm)? I've found pycharm can also cause random issues sometimes

Comment: I was able to install all requirements, but just out of curiosity I ran `python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall -r requirements.txt` and at least now it seems to fail consistently while uninstalling `cffi` (when using admin cmd or Pycharm). Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have the problem, that sometimes code doesn't work due to a very long path.
Try to reinstall python(/the venv python) and search for a point where you can check a box so that the path isn't limited anymore

Comment: I checked my registry and found 
`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled` is set to `0x00000001 (1)`, which should enable "long paths" system-wide, so I assume that this should not be the issue. Thank you for your suggestion though, I did not think about that.